# Трудности с кодом javascript

Tags: javascript

У меня возникли трудности со следующим кодом:

```
<!-- STEP ONE: Paste this code into the HEAD of your HTML document  -->

<HEAD>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Original:  Maximilian Stocker (maxstocker@reallyusefulcomputing.com) -->

<!-- This script and many more are available free online at -->
<!-- The JavaScript Source!! http://javascript.internet.com -->

<!-- Begin
var x = "img/x.jpg";
// Location of where you uploaded your site's x.jpg image

var o = "img/o.jpg";
// Location of where you uploaded your site's o.jpg image

var blank = "img/blank.jpg";
// Location of where you uploaded your site's blank.jpg image

var pause = 0;
var all = 0;
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
var d = 0;
var e = 0;
var f = 0;
var g = 0;
var h = 0;
var i = 0;
var temp="";
var ok = 0;
var cf = 0;
var choice=9;
var aRandomNumber = 0;
var comp = 0; 
var t = 0;
var wn = 0;
var ls = 0;
var ts = 0;

function logicOne() {
if ((a==1)&&(b==1)&&(c==1)) all=1;
if ((a==1)&&(d==1)&&(g==1)) all=1;
if ((a==1)&&(e==1)&&(i==1)) all=1;
if ((b==1)&&(e==1)&&(h==1)) all=1;
if ((d==1)&&(e==1)&&(f==1)) all=1;
if ((g==1)&&(h==1)&&(i==1)) all=1;
if ((c==1)&&(f==1)&&(i==1)) all=1;
if ((g==1)&&(e==1)&&(c==1)) all=1;
if ((a==2)&&(b==2)&&(c==2)) all=2;
if ((a==2)&&(d==2)&&(g==2)) all=2;
if ((a==2)&&(e==2)&&(i==2)) all=2;
if ((b==2)&&(e==2)&&(h==2)) all=2;
if ((d==2)&&(e==2)&&(f==2)) all=2;
if ((g==2)&&(h==2)&&(i==2)) all=2;
if ((c==2)&&(f==2)&&(i==2)) all=2;
if ((g==2)&&(e==2)&&(c==2)) all=2;
if ((a != 0)&&(b != 0)&&(c != 0)&&(d != 0)&&(e != 0)&&(f != 0)&&(g != 0)&&(h != 0)&&(i != 0)&&(all == 0)) all = 3;
} 
function logicTwo() {
if ((a==2)&&(b==2)&&(c== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="C";
if ((a==2)&&(b== 0)&&(c==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="B";
if ((a== 0)&&(b==2)&&(c==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="A";
if ((a==2)&&(d==2)&&(g== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="G";
if ((a==2)&&(d== 0)&&(g==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="D";
if ((a== 0)&&(d==2)&&(g==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="A";
if ((a==2)&&(e==2)&&(i== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="I";
if ((a==2)&&(e== 0)&&(i==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((a== 0)&&(e==2)&&(i==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="A";
if ((b==2)&&(e==2)&&(h== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="H";
if ((b==2)&&(e== 0)&&(h==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((b== 0)&&(e==2)&&(h==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="B";
if ((d==2)&&(e==2)&&(f== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="F";
if ((d==2)&&(e== 0)&&(f==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((d== 0)&&(e==2)&&(f==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="D";
if ((g==2)&&(h==2)&&(i== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="I";
if ((g==2)&&(h== 0)&&(i==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="H";
if ((g== 0)&&(h==2)&&(i==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="G";
if ((c==2)&&(f==2)&&(i== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="I";
if ((c==2)&&(f== 0)&&(i==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="F";
if ((c== 0)&&(f==2)&&(i==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="C";
if ((g==2)&&(e==2)&&(c== 0)&&(temp=="")) temp="C";
if ((g==2)&&(e== 0)&&(c==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((g== 0)&&(e==2)&&(c==2)&&(temp=="")) temp="G";
}
function logicThree() {
if ((a==1)&&(b==1)&&(c==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="C";
if ((a==1)&&(b==0)&&(c==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="B";
if ((a==0)&&(b==1)&&(c==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="A";
if ((a==1)&&(d==1)&&(g==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="G";
if ((a==1)&&(d==0)&&(g==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="D";
if ((a==0)&&(d==1)&&(g==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="A";
if ((a==1)&&(e==1)&&(i==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="I";
if ((a==1)&&(e==0)&&(i==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((a==0)&&(e==1)&&(i==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="A";
if ((b==1)&&(e==1)&&(h==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="H";
if ((b==1)&&(e==0)&&(h==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((b==0)&&(e==1)&&(h==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="B";
if ((d==1)&&(e==1)&&(f==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="F";
if ((d==1)&&(e==0)&&(f==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((d==0)&&(e==1)&&(f==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="D";
if ((g==1)&&(h==1)&&(i==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="I";
if ((g==1)&&(h==0)&&(i==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="H";
if ((g==0)&&(h==1)&&(i==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="G";
if ((c==1)&&(f==1)&&(i==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="I";
if ((c==1)&&(f==0)&&(i==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="F";
if ((c==0)&&(f==1)&&(i==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="C";
if ((g==1)&&(e==1)&&(c==0)&&(temp=="")) temp="C";
if ((g==1)&&(e==0)&&(c==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="E";
if ((g==0)&&(e==1)&&(c==1)&&(temp=="")) temp="G";
}
function clearOut() {
document.game.you.value="0";
document.game.computer.value="0";
document.game.ties.value="0";
}
function checkSpace() {
if ((temp=="A")&&(a==0)) {
ok=1;
if (cf==0) a=1;
if (cf==1) a=2;
}
if ((temp=="B")&&(b==0)) {
ok=1;
if (cf==0) b=1;
if (cf==1) b=2;
}
if ((temp=="C")&&(c==0)) {
ok=1;
if (cf==0) c=1;
if (cf==1) c=2;
}
if ((temp=="D")&&(d==0)) {
ok=1;
if (cf==0) d=1;
if (cf==1) d=2;
}
if ((temp=="E")&&(e==0)) {
ok=1;
if (cf==0) e=1;
if (cf==1) e=2;
}
if ((temp=="F")&&(f==0)) {
ok=1
if (cf==0) f=1;
if (cf==1) f=2;
}
if ((temp=="G")&&(g==0)) {
ok=1
if (cf==0) g=1;
if (cf==1) g=2;
}
if ((temp=="H")&&(h==0)) {
ok=1;
if (cf==0) h=1;
if (cf==1) h=2;
}
if ((temp=="I")&&(i==0)) {
ok=1;
if (cf==0) i=1; 
if (cf==1) i=2; 
}
}
function yourChoice(chName) {
pause = 0;
if (all!=0) ended();
if (all==0) {
cf = 0;
ok = 0;
temp=chName;
checkSpace();
if (ok==1) {
document.images[chName].src = x;
}
if (ok==0)taken();
process();
if ((all==0)&&(pause==0)) myChoice();
   }
}
function taken() {
alert("That square is already occupied.  Please select another square.")
pause=1;
}
function myChoice() {
temp="";
ok = 0;
cf=1;
logicTwo();
logicThree();
checkSpace();
while(ok==0) {
aRandomNumber=Math.random()
comp=Math.round((choice-1)*aRandomNumber)+1;
if (comp==1) temp="A";
if (comp==2) temp="B";
if (comp==3) temp="C";
if (comp==4) temp="D";
if (comp==5) temp="E";
if (comp==6) temp="F";
if (comp==7) temp="G";
if (comp==8) temp="H";
if (comp==9) temp="I";
checkSpace();
}
document.images[temp].src= o;
process();
}
function ended() {
alert("The game has already ended. To play a new game click the Play Again button.")
}
function process() {
logicOne();
if (all==1){ alert("You won, congratulations!"); wn++; }
if (all==2){ alert("Gotcha!  I win!"); ls++; }
if (all==3){ alert("We tied."); ts++; }
if (all!=0) {
document.game.you.value = wn;
document.game.computer.value = ls;
document.game.ties.value = ts;
   }
}
function playAgain() {
if (all==0) {
if(confirm("This will restart the game and clear all the current scores. OK?")) reset();
}
if (all>0) reset();
}
function reset() {
all = 0;
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
d = 0;
e = 0;
f = 0;
g = 0;
h = 0;
i = 0;
temp="";
ok = 0;
cf = 0;
choice=9;
aRandomNumber = 0;
comp = 0; 
document.images.A.src= blank;
document.images.B.src= blank;
document.images.C.src= blank;
document.images.D.src= blank;
document.images.E.src= blank;
document.images.F.src= blank;
document.images.G.src= blank;
document.images.H.src= blank;
document.images.I.src= blank;
if (t==0) { t=2; myChoice(); }
t--;
}
//  End -->
</script>
</HEAD>

<!-- STEP TWO: Copy this code into the BODY of your HTML document  -->

<BODY>

<center>
<form name=game>
<table border=0>
<td>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('A')"><img src="img/blank.jpg" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=A alt="Top-Left"></a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('B')"><img src="img/blank.jpg" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=B alt="Top-Center"></a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('C')"><img src="img/blank.jpg" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=C alt="Top-Right"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('D')"><img src="img/blank.jpg" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=D alt="Middle-Left"></a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('E')"><img src="img/blank.jpg" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=E alt="Middle-Center"></a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('F')"><img src="img/blank.jpg" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=F alt="Middle-Right"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('G')"><img src="img/blank.jpg" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=G alt="Bottom-Left"></a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('H')"><img src="img/blank.jpg" border=0 height=100 width=100 name=H alt="Bottom-Center"></a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:yourChoice('I')"><img src="img/blank.jpg" border=0 height=100 width=100  name=I alt="Bottom-Right"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>
<table>
<tr><td><input type=text size=5 name=you></td><td>You</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=text size=5 name=computer></td><td>Computer</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=text size=5 name=ties></td><td>Ties</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</table>
<input type=button value="Play Again" onClick="playAgain();">
</form>
</center>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, какова роль вот этих функций в нем: `checkSpace()`, `yourChoice(chName)` и `myChoice()`?
И для чего эти переменные: `pause`, `temp`, `ok`, `cf`, `choice`, `aRandomNumber`, `comp` и `t`?

ответе пожалуйста очень нужно:)

Comment: отформатируете код, читать не возможно. Поставьте табуляцию в блоках, то есть { } - все что в таких скобках, отделяется одним табом. Читать не возможно эту мешанину, без этого вам ни кто не поможет.

Comment: код так и просится на govnokod.ru

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Похоже на крестики-нолики. Очень хреново написанные. Очень.

Переменные с `a` по `i` задают доску 3x3. Автора в аду для быдлокодеров уже ждут вилы за неумение пользоваться массивами.

Переменная `cf` определяет чей сейчас ход. Выставляется в начале `myChoice()` и `yourChoice()`.

Функции `yourChoice()` и `myChoice()` отвечают за установку хода. `yourChoice()` вызывается javascript: ссылками в документе и принимает имя позиции (A..I), `myChoice()` использует жестко закодированный автомат, описанный функциями `logicOne()/logicTwo()/logicThree()` (для первого, второго и третьего кода, соответственно). За неумение нормально реализовывать конечные автоматы автору добавляется порицание общественности.

Переменная `pause` «отвечает» за приостанов работы на время, пока пользователь делает ход. В `yourChoice()` она снимается в `0`. Если ход был некорректен (занят), то в `taken()`, вызываемом из `yourChoice()` она возвращается в `1`. По сути, `pause` определяет, будет ли в конце `yourChoice()` вызвана `myChoice()` для хода компьютера.

В `temp` хранится позиция, в которую делается код.

За вынос всякого барахла в «глобальные» переменные инквизиция выдвигает обвинение в наведение порчи на области видимости переменных и к вилам добавляется острый кол.

Функция `checkSpace` проверяет, можно ли поставить ход в клетку, сохраненную в `temp`. Выставляет соответствующую переменную `a..i` в `1` или `2`, в зависимости от `cf` (к вилам и колу добавляется дыба за то, что не смог написать `var = cf;` (опционально, `+ 1`, если не хочется менять {0, 1} на {1, 2}) и наворотил `if`'ов) и `ok` в `1`, если можно. Поскольку `ok` в `checkSpace` не обнуляется (и все работает только за счет обнуления ее в `myChoice()`/`yourChoice()`), то к вилам, колу и дыбе добавляется удобный и просторный плавательный котел с кипящим маслом.

`aRandomNumber` — бесполезная переменная, хранящее результат `Math.random()` — случайное число в интервале [0, 1). Зачем нужна эта переменная, и почему нельзя было умножить сразу — науке остается неизвестным. Неисповедимы пути индусские.

`comp` — принимает случайное значение в интервале [1, 9] (т.е. `Math.round(8 * Math.random()) + 1`). Распределение вероятности неравномерное, вероятность получения девятки ниже, чем остальных вариантов (`Math.random()` должно выбросить больше 8.5). Имеет то же значение, что и `temp` только вместо `A..I` использует `1..9`. Помним об ожидающем автора коле, да.

`t` — счетчик ходов, что ли. Считает от 2 до 0, если равна 0, то вызывается `myChoice()` и `t` становится равной двум (начало новой игры).

В общем, не портите себе карму, выкиньте поскорее эту ересь и напишите что-нибудь нормальное.

Comment: и ведь не поленился разобраться и столько написать ) уважаю.

Comment: Да уж, неисповедимы пути индусские. ))